# Prove that the cross ratio of four distinct points is real iff the four points lie on single Euclidean line or circle

Tags: complex-analysis, euclidean-geometry, circles, cross-ratio

I have started this proof by rewriting the formula for the cross ratio in terms of the polar decomposition of complex numbers:

$r=\Big(\dfrac{z_1-z_3}{z_1-z_4}\Big)\Big(\dfrac{z_2-z_4}{z_2-z_3}\Big)=\Big|\dfrac{z_1-z_3}{z_1-z_4}\Big|\Big|\dfrac{z_2-z_4}{z_2- z_3}\Big|e^{i(\theta_1+\theta_2)}$

So now I know that for this to be real I need $\theta_1+\theta_2$ to be a multiple of $\pi$ but how can I prove that this only holds for circles or Euclidean lines?

I know there are other ways to prove this but this is the proof that follows the flow of the project I am working on so would like to try and continue with this proof.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** We either have $\theta_1\equiv \theta_2\equiv 0\pmod{\pi} $ when they lie on a line. 
In any other cases you can use a theorem for inscribed quadrangles to conclude they lie on a circle.

Comment: I know here is a theorem for opposite angles in a cyclic quadrilateral and I understand the straight line argument but how can I show that the sum cannot be a multiple of $\pi$ for any other shape?

Comment: Ahh.. I think I misunderstood your question. So, you get that $(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)$ real implies they on a line or circle. Its converse also holds: if $z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4$ are on a line or circle, then we get a real number for their cross ratio.

Comment: If the sum $\theta_1+\theta_2$ is $\pi$, then it's again an inscribed quadrangle..